# SEPA processing in Java

Tags: java

Does anyone know where I can find following SEPA libraries? I want to build a processor for SEPA Bank statements

```
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.AccountInterest2;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.AccountStatement2;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.BankToCustomerStatementV02;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.CashAccount16;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.CashAccount20;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.CashBalance3;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.CopyDuplicate1Code;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.DateTimePeriodDetails;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.Document;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.GroupHeader42;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.Pagination;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.PartyIdentification32;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.ReportEntry2;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.ReportingSource1Choice;
import iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.camt_053_001.TotalTransactions2;
```

Thanks, and best regards,

Pierre

Answer (score 4):

These classes are generated from the xsd file. I am not sure where to download it officially, but once you have it, you can add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
             <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>camt.053.001.02.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to find it anywhere. How would I generate that?

Comment: You do not generate it, but have to download it from some official sources. As already said I do not now where to download it officially, but googling it leads me to https://www.iso20022.org/payments_messages.page, but you should check if their license allows free (commercial) usage of the file.

Comment: @PierreSmits How you came across this classes anyway, when not having the xsd or the lib?

Comment: Using the jaxb function I refactored the xsd's provided into java libraries.

Comment: I found the references on github.

Comment: XSD files can be found on https://www.iso20022.org/message_archive.page too, under XML Schema fields.